# "Too many open files" error uploading with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, paperclip

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Paperclip to upload/store images for a photo website. The form is nested for albums and photos. The Album model contains the lines

```
attr_accessible :photos_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

And the Photo model

```
has_attached_file :photo
```

So the form has an input

```
<input type="file" name="album[photos_attributes][][photo]" multiple="true">
```

It works perfectly for a few photos, but when I try to upload a ton, as a user might since it's a photo website, I get the error "Too many open files."

From what I read, it seems like it's because of the way Paperclip handles opening files and not closing them, so I need to manually close them? The Album#create controller action looks like this:

```
def create
  @album = Album.new(params[:album])
  if @album.save
    redirect_to album_url(@album)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

What do I need to add here to get this to work? Thanks in advance.